# Why C# import only works inside namespace

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working in a Unity project 3D.

When i try to extend or use an especific class called `Ability`, the IDE forces me to do a full import of the class by adding the namespace into declaration.

This don't work (Normal import outside namespace):

```
using CarlaFramework.Opsive.UltimateCharacterController.Scripts.Character.Abilities;


namespace CarlaFramework.uiMonitor {
      public abstract class DoozyViewAbilityMonitor : SerializedMonoBehaviour
      {
         private Ability currentAbility;
      }
}
```

This works (Import in declaration statement):

```
protected CarlaFramework.Opsive.UltimateCharacterController.Scripts.Character.Abilities.Ability currentAbility;
```

This also works (Import inside namespace declaration):

```
namespace CarlaFramework.uiMonitor 
{

   using Opsive.UltimateCharacterController.Scripts.Character.Abilities;

   public abstract class DoozyViewAbilityMonitor : SerializedMonoBehaviour
   {
      private Ability currentAbility;
   }
}
```

Code image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WC1JP.jpg

Comment: The actual error it showed in your video was only up for a fraction of a second, required careful pausing to see what it said.  It looks like "Import ... and other missing references", where ... is the assembly containing the type.  So if you told it to import that reference, it would have added that assembly to your project, and then you should be able to refer to it either way.

Comment: Sorry for the video. Yes it suggest 'Import missing references in file' and what that do, is to write full namespace of the class in the declaration statement. I'd like to import it by the keyword "using", but it don't take it. https://imgur.com/UWN2Ybs   (Here: In the image you can see i have the using and that namespace have the class. But the IDE just don't take it)

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills i wish i could, but i don't know how to reproduce the error. 

The only thing i discovered recently, was that if i make the import `using` inside the namespace, then it works. Outside don't. https://imgur.com/QFDrUFR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was, that I had a namespace whose name was clashing with the name of a class (`Ability`).

When I tried to declare variables of `Ability` type, I had to write the full namespace to let the IDE know which I meant:

```
protected CarlaFramework.Opsive.UltimateCharacterController.Scripts.Character.Abilities.Ability currentAbility;
```

By simply renaming the namespace, the problem went away.

Here is the name clash:

[image]

Comment: Just for future reference, you can also see this if you use a namespace like `Foo.MySpace.Ability`. That syntax is a quick way of defining [nested namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/namespaces#namespace-declarations). Just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example isn't an import - it's the fully-qualified name of the type. You can't import an assembly reference like that from within a class.

There are two different meanings to `using`:

1. As a directive, like you're trying to use it (to import a namespace). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive. The gist is that you can't import a reference inline (within a class or struct).
2. As a scoping block, which is primarily (only?) used to make sure an IDisposable has it's `Dispose()` method called. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Comment: I understand, perhaps i choosed poorly my words. My question is, why this behavior happened with that namespace and not with the others? https://imgur.com/QFDrUFR Here i have an image, where i'm referencing others fully-qualified name without troubles

Comment: There's two things happening in that screenshot: a) The grey text is just Visual Studio telling you that the namespace isn't used anywhere, b) Your namespace for that file is hiding the name of the class. So, VS doesn't know if you mean the namespace Ability or the class named Ability.

Comment: You nailed it in the **b**.

I was hiding the name of the class, because i have another namespace called `Ability` so when i tried to make an import Rider, had to complete the full namespace to avoid clash. If you modify your answer with this, i'll marked it as accepted. Thank you Tieson, you're great!

Comment: @Haytam95 Probably be better if you self-answer this (pretty much what you said, but elaborate a bit more). If you do that, I'll edit it to expand anything I think you missed or I think worth emphasizing.